# Is it possible to restrict an abstract class to have only final and abstract methods

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstraction

I am having a multi levels inheriting structure. Say a base class **Car** which is inherited by **AutoGear** and **ManualGear**. Say, classes **Jaguar** and **BMW** extends **AutoGear** and **Honda** extends **ManualGear**. Now, in class **Car**, i should have only final methods like:

```
protected final int getWheels(){
return 4;
}
```

or

```
protected abstract int getTopSpeed();
```

and I should not have any other methods which is implemented in class **Car** but prone for overriding by child classes. Is that possible?

Comment: short answer to your title. No

Comment: If it's *implemented* in `Car` (that is, it's *not* abstract), then you can declare it final, and the children cannot redefine it. If it's abstract, that means the children are *supposed* to override it, so you can't declare it as final - it doesn't make sense. So what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Car is an abstract class. I would like to implement only the hard defined "Not gonna change" piece of code in that particular class. This is because, my levels tend to grow and I do not want each subclass to override with regard to its own implementation and then cause logical confusions on calling super methods.

Comment: or I can have only abstract methods so that each class can implement itself and super.method would not be possible since the super's method is abstract.

Comment: Then use `protected final` or `public final` methods for these, as you did for `getWheels`. The children will be able to access but not override them. I still don't see what you need that you are not getting at the moment.

Comment: yes, that is fine and that is what Am doing. But what I want to do is to restrict the entire class **Car** to have only final or abstract methods.

Comment: What good will that do you? If you write this and ship it as a library, users don't have access to the source and can't rewrite the `Car` class. If you share it in your organization, you are supposed to trust your team - if they can access the code and change it, they can also change the magic incantation that says it can't be changed...

Comment: I suppose you can write a static checker that checks your requirement, maybe through reflection, and issues an error message for each method that doesn’t fulfil your requirement.